# IIS Returning 200 instead of 404 for a Page

Tags: asp.net, iis, proxy, iis-7, ashx

I have a website I'm hosting in IIS.  I've been trying to hit it a certain path, but IIS strangely has been returning a 200 with no content (content-length=0) to me.

I'm doing a POST to something like https://example.com/path/something/proxy.ashx?someurl

I changed the proxy.ashx file to proxy1.ashx, figuring that the calls should now return 404, instead of 200.

Nope! I keep getting 200s for these calls, despite renaming the file.  I can see IIS logging the 200s in the inetpup logs.  I made sure that IIS has .ashx as registered in IIS's MIME types with the type: application/octet-stream

Any ideas on why IIS is behaving this way?

Comment: Dig into the 200 responses, like headers and so on. Use them as hints for further troubleshooting and also improve the question body.

Comment: Are you showing a 404 page?

Comment: I get no headers, no content back.  It's like the IIS just terminates the request.  I did check that I have the IIS static content features installed on the server.    The response I get has no headers, no body, 200 response code, and content length of 0.